# jquery validate() on mouse out in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js, jquery-validate

I'm using [jquery.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=mouse) to validate my registration form, everything is working well but I have one problem with `email` field of my form, because I added a custome method to check whether `email` is existed or not in database.

Here is my implement :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var _user = new User();
   $.validator.addMethod(
         "isEmailExist",
         function(value, element) {
             return _user.isEmailNotExist(value);
         },
         "Username is Already Taken"
   );

   $("#registerForm").validate({
     rules: {
         firstname: {
             required : true,
             maxlength: 30
         },
         lastname:  {
             required : true,
             maxlength: 30
         },
         password: {
             required: true,
             minlength: 5,
             maxlength: 30
         }
         email: {
             required: true,
             email: true,
             maxlength: 30,
             isEmailExist : true
         }
     },
     messages: {
         firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
         lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
         password: {
             required: "Please provide a password",
             minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
         },
         email: {
             email : "Please enter a valid email address",
             isEmailExist : "This email is already existed"
         }
     }
    });
 });
```

**Problem** : Whenever I enter a character in `email` field, `isEmailNotExist()` is working, so it takes awhile to validate the text box.

**What I want** : is to validate the `email` field only when I move my mouse out.

Any help would be appreciated. And is it a good solution to validate it on mouse out? Thanks.

Comment: Try using [onKeyup](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup) option. Set it to false.

Comment: @ManishMulimani : Where should I use it?

Comment: $("#registerForm").validate({ onkeyup: false, rules: {
         firstname: {....} });

Comment: @ManishMulimani : But I want just only `email` rule in that `keyup` case.

Comment: `keyup` is applicable to all rules, can't be assigned to a single rule.